# infinite scrolling stops if I zoom my browser

Tags: jquery, html, infinite-scroll

I've got a page with infinite scrolling that works fine when the user's browser's zoom is at 100%. If the user zooms in on the page or zooms out (ie anything other than 100%) the scrolling eventually breaks and the page will stop retrieving records, even though there are many more to get.

How do I correct that?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test2.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html){
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                        }else{
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>That\'s the Last One!</center>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>

    <style>
      .postitem{
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 5px 0 15px 0;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hycucdemosbody">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="postswrapper">
            <?php
            for($counter=0; $counter <= 50; $counter += 1){
              echo "\n".'<div class="postitem" id="'.$counter.'">Post no '.$counter.'</div>';           
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="display:none;"><center><img src="ajax-loader.gif"/></center></div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here's test2.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['lastid'])){
$counter=addslashes($_GET['lastid']) + 1;
$total=$counter+25;
  for($counter; $counter <= $total; $counter += 1){
   echo "\n".'<div class="postitem" id="'.$counter.'">Post no '.$counter.'</div>';          
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Possible solution

Just to make sure,
Check out [this link](http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/), and see if that solution might do you any better. It checks when you've hit the bottom of the scroll. It's really accurate!

```
<div id="box" style="height:300px; overflow:auto;">
  <div class="inner">
    <!-- Your content goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var elem = $('#box');
var inner = $('#box > .inner');
if ( Math.abs(inner.offset().top) + elem.height() + elem.offset().top >= inner.outerHeight() ) {
  // We're at the bottom!
}
```

---

### Checking zoom ratio

Hm, if that doesn't work, I'd suggest you take a look at [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers).

They discuss how to detect the amount of zoom in different browsers. 
You can, from there, correct your code to account for the zoom when determining the end of scroll.

---

### Infinite scroll plugins

Other than that, I'd suggest you look into some of the alternative plugins that manage infinite scrolling
Like

- [scrollLoad](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/scrollLoad)
- [Infinite Scroll jQuery Plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/)

I could probably list a few others, but it's easier just to do a google search, there are so many of them.

---

Happy coding and good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

when zoom in,

```
console.log('document height'+jQuery(document).height());  ---15138
console.log('window scrollTop'+jQuery(window).scrollTop());---13926.25
console.log('window height'+jQuery(window).height());      ---1211
```

and the sum of jQuery(window).scrollTop() and jQuery(window).height() is 0.75 lower than jQuery(document).height().

So I add 2

```
    if (jQuery(document).height() <= jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() + 2)
```

Hope it works for you